# Modeshape JDBC connector: references between tables

Tags: jdbc, foreign-keys, modeshape

I'm using Modeshape with jdbc-metadata-connector. It obtains database structure into the storage.

But I couldn't find any way to obtain information about references between tables (foreign keys): all the foreign keys have corresponding dbms data types and there are no extra columns with `REF` type.

How can I obtain information about foreign keys in the database?

Thank you for any help. Have a good day!

---

[Modeshape's JIRA feature request](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MODE-1610)

Comment: The `java.sql.Types.REF` type is not a foreign key reference like you seem to think.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Is that `cursor`?

Comment: SQL:2003 (section 4.9 in Foundation) says this _A REF value is a value that references a row in a referenceable table (see Subclause 4.14.5, “Referenceable
tables, subtables, and supertables”). A referenceable table is necessarily also a typed table (that is, it has an
associated structured type from which its row type is derived)._ Not sure if it is helpful though. I believe Oracle supports it with the REF type: http://psoug.org/definition/REF.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata connector does not yet provide foreign key relationships. Feel free to log a feature request in [ModeShape's JIRA system](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/MODE).